# Add an ID Attribute for Element EncryptedAssertion or EncryptedData in RSTR from PingFederate

Tags: cxf, pingfederate, ws-trust

I'm using Apache CXF 3.1.5 to work with PingFederate 7.2. 
In PingFederate, I create a WS-Trust SP connection, if the SAML Assertion is not encrypted. it works well. 
If the SAML Assertion is encrypted, then it doesn't work, because **CXF** requires an **Id** Attribute for Element **EncryptedAssertion** or **EncryptedData** in **RSTR** from PingFederate. While, PingFederate **doesn't** provide such an Id attribute.
so I have two questions.

1. Why does **CXF** require an **Id** attribute(method ***createSecurityToken*** in class ***AbstractSTSClient***)? It seems the standard specifications say that the **Id** attribute is optional.
2. How can I add an **Id** attribute for Element **EncryptedAssertion** or **EncryptedData** in PingFederate? or is there something else I can do?

Thanks a lot!

[RSTR from PingFederate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0KcFt.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I loosened the requirement for an ID in CXF.

Fixed here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CXF-7003